# Meteorjs sendVerificationEmail error

Tags: meteor

I setup the EMAIL_URL

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://xx%40gmail.com:yyy@smtp.gmail.com:465"
```

This worked find with

```
Email.send({
    to: 'a@exmaple.com',
    from: 'b@exmaple.com',
    subject: 'test',
    text: 'some text'
});
```

However this failed

```
Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
})

or

Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId,email)
```

giving me errors

Exception while invoking method 'createUser' RecipientError: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected

at Object.Future.wait (.meteor\tools\dc9fb5197a\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:326:15)

at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:91)

at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:152)

at Object.Accounts.sendVerificationEmail (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:571)

at packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:692

at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:171)

at Object.Accounts._loginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:287)

at Meteor.methods.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:668)

at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1487)

at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:643

---

at SMTPClient._actionRCPT (.meteor\packages\email\a59237d5f0\npm\node_modules\simplesmtp\lib\client.js:909:27)

at SMTPClient._onData (.meteor\packages\email\a59237d5f0\npm\node_modules\simplesmtp\lib\client.js:329:29)

at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)

at CleartextStream. (_stream_readable.js:748:14)

at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:92:17)

at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)

at _stream_readable.js:403:7

at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same error. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately... no, I moved to mailgun

Comment: @Sebi55 I had the same problem but fixed it by setting Accounts.emailTemplates.from

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding the following to my server code:

`Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "myemailaddress@example.com";`

I don't know why this should matter because I had already properly set my MAIL_URL with my username, but it does! :)